# Total flux of the gradient of the numerical solution of a PDE through a surface

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, heat-equation

Trying to solve the following PDE with BC `T==1` on a spherical cap of a unit sphere and `T==0` at infinity (approximated as `r==(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.5==40^0.5`) and the flux over the remaining surfaces taken to be zero (only half domains has been specified due to symmetry reasons):

```
p = 0.2;
Pe = 20;
<< NDSolve`FEM`
boundaries = {-x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 40, -y, 
   z - p + 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ boundaries), {x, y, z}]];
Show[\[CapitalOmega][
  "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", Boxed -> True]], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-0.5, 7}, {-7, 1}}]
Show[\[CapitalOmega]["Wireframe"], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-0.5, 7}, {-7, 1}}]
```

[image: dominio]

The free-surface is located at `z==-0.8` in the chosen reference system.
The differential equation is:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[T[x, y, z], x] == 
    1/Pe Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {DirichletCondition[
     T[x, y, z] == 1., boundaries[[1]] == 0.],
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 0., boundaries[[2]] == 0.]}}, 
  T, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

I noticed a non-smooth behavior of the solution `sol`, as confirmed by the density plots:

```
z1 = -0.8;
DensityPlot[sol[x, y, z1], {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
DensityPlot[sol[x, 0, z], {x, -4, 4}, {z, -0.8, -2}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]

and by some plots of the solution

```
Plot[sol[x, 0, -0.8], {x, 0.6, 6.1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 7}, {-0.1, 1.2}}]
Plot[sol[x, 0, -0.8], {x, -6.1, -0.6}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-7, 0.1}, {-0.1, 1.2}}]
```

[image: fig3]
[image: fig4]

The derivatives of the solution show an even worse behavior. I report here as example just the derivative with respect to `x`:

```
Dr[x_, y_, z_] = D[sol[x, y, z], x]
Plot[Dr[x, 0, -0.8], {x, 0.6, 8}, Frame -> True]
Plot[Dr[x, 0, -0.8], {x, -8, -0.6}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: fig5]
[image: fig6]

I am interested in the derivative because I am trying to calculate the total flux of the gradient of `sol` through the two portion of the spherical cap, `SC1` and `SC2`, which border the domain. As known, this is proportional to the heat flow through `SC1` and `SC2`. The definition of `SC1` and `SC2` is:

```
SC1 = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && z <= p - 1 && y >= 0 && x >= 0, {x, y, z}];
SC2 = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 && z <= p - 1 && y >= 0 && x <= 0, {x, y, z}];
Show[DiscretizeRegion[SC1, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.2, 1}, {-0.8, -1}}]
Show[DiscretizeRegion[SC2, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.2, 1}, {-0.8, -1}}]
```

and the heat flow through `SC1` and `SC2` should be:

```
NIntegrate[#, {x, y, z} \[Element] SC1] & /@ (Grad[
    sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}].{x, y, z})
NIntegrate[#, {x, y, z} \[Element] SC2] & /@ (Grad[
    sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}].{x, y, z})
```

Unfortunately, I get a lot of errors from the last calculation, I don't know if this happens because of the non-smooth behavior of the solution and of the derivative or for other mistakes that I am doing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mesh is too bad. May be you should restrict solution to `x^2+y^2+z^2<=4&&x>=0&& y >= 0 && z <= -1 + p`, with mesh of 50323 Tetrahedron Element (MaxCellMeasure -> .0001), check solution and then try to expand region.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic problem appears to be a convective-diffusive heat transfer problem of X-directed fluid flow across a heated spherical cap tip. To study this type of problem, it probably is easier to construct a virtual cuboid wind tunnel. When simulating virtual wind tunnels, the upstream section is typically much shorter than the downstream week region, so there really is not any spherical symmetry.

The following workflow will show how to construct a virtual wind tunnel and add refinement zones so that gradients may be captured near the object of interest without blowing up the total model size.

## Virtual wind tunnel construction with refinement zones.

As discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173762/61809), a `MeshRefinementFunction` will not necessarily refine the surface mesh in 3D. The suggested workaround was to use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) to obtain a finely discretized surface mesh on the input geometry before applying the `MeshRefinementFunction`.

The following workflow creates a refined region with a finely discretized tip and a wind tunnel domain less refined region:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
Pe = 15;
tip = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], MaxCellMeasure -> .00125, 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];
refCuboid = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{-1.5, 0, -1.5}, {3.5, 1.5, -0.8}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> .01, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];
reftip = RegionDifference[refCuboid, tip, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
domCuboid = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{-2.5, 0, -3.8}, {7.5, 4, -0.8}], 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];
domref = RegionDifference[domCuboid, refCuboid, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image: Basic wind tunnel shapes]

### Create volume mesh with refinement zones

The following workflow creates a refinement zone with a high level of surface discretization at the tip. The total number of elements is about 134,000, which does not take too long to solve.

```
(* Create Mesh Refinement Function *)
mrf = With[{rmf = RegionMember[reftip]}, 
   Function[{vertices, volume}, 
    Block[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Mean[vertices]; 
     If[rmf[{x, y, z}], volume > (0.07/1.5)^3, volume > (0.3)^3]]]];
(* Create and Display Volumetric Mesh *)
mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionUnion[domref, reftip], 
  MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal", "MeshElementConstraint" -> 40, 
  "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> .1}, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf]
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements",
  "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Black]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2.5`, 7.5`}, {0.2, 
     4.`}, {-3.8`, -0.7999999999999998`}}]]
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
```

[image: Mesh]

## Solution

We and solve and now compare our solution on the refined mesh versus the OP mesh.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[T[x, y, z], x] == 
     1/Pe Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {DirichletCondition[
      T[x, y, z] == 1., ElementMarker == 3], 
     DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 0., ElementMarker == 4]}}, 
   T, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
z1 = -0.8;
DensityPlot[sol[x, y, z1], {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
DensityPlot[sol[x, 0, z], {x, -4, 4}, {z, -0.8, -2}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Density plots]

Visually, the solution appears to be much smoother than the images shown in the OP.

### Other plots

The other plots appear much smoother with the refined mesh.

```
Plot[sol[x, 0, -0.8], {x, 0.6, 6.1}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 7}, {-0.1, 1.2}}]
Plot[sol[x, 0, -0.8], {x, -6.1, -0.6}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-7, 0.1}, {-0.1, 1.2}}]
Dr[x_, y_, z_] = D[sol[x, y, z], x];
Plot[Dr[x, 0, -0.8], {x, 0.6, 8}, Frame -> True]
Plot[Dr[x, 0, -0.8], {x, -8, -0.6}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Other plots]

## Integration of total flux

### Using [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

The integration strategy given in the OP does solve albeit quite slowly due to slow convergence issues. When I evaluate the OP code, I obtained:

```
NIntegrate[#, {x, y, z} ∈ SC1] & /@ (Grad[
    sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] . {x, y, z})
NIntegrate[#, {x, y, z} ∈ SC2] & /@ (Grad[
    sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] . {x, y, z})
(* -0.95414 *)
(* -2.96035 *)
```

### Summing up the discretized data

Using a variety of Mathematica functions, we can extract the normals, areas, and thermal gradients of each triangle on the mesh corresponding to the spherical cap. This should be enough information to estimate an integrated flux.

The following workflow shows how to extract the necessary information for the left and right-hand sides of the spherical cap.

```
(*Element info shortcuts*)
ebi = ElementIncidents[#["BoundaryElements"]][[1]] &;
ebm = ElementMarkers[#["BoundaryElements"]][[1]] &;
ebn = #["BoundaryNormals"][[1]] &;
ei = ElementIncidents[#["MeshElements"]][[1]] &;
em = ElementMarkers[#["MeshElements"]][[1]] &;
epi = ElementIncidents[#["PointElements"]][[1]] &;
epm = Flatten@ElementMarkers[#["PointElements"]] &;
(*extract boundary mesh from element mesh*)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
bcrd = bmesh["Coordinates"];
bi = ebi[bmesh];(*boundary element incidents*)
bm = ebm[bmesh];(*boundary element markers*)
bn = ebn[bmesh];(*boundary normals*)
(*find markers corresponding to the spherical cap*)
mrk3pos = Flatten@Position[bm, 3, 1];
(*generate necessary info to estimate surface integral*)
bn3 = bn[[mrk3pos]];
polys = Map[Polygon, 
   GetElementCoordinates[bcrd, #] & /@ bi[[mrk3pos]]];
area3 = Area /@ polys;
center3 = Map[Mean, GetElementCoordinates[bcrd, #] & /@ bi[[mrk3pos]]];
(*find positions of left and right side of spherical cap*)
posXids = Position[center3[[All, 1]], _?(# >= 0 &), 1] // Flatten;
negXids = Complement[Range[Length[mrk3pos]], posXids];
Show[{Graphics3D[{Red, polys[[posXids]]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, polys[[negXids]]}]}]
```

[image: Left and right-hand side of spherical cap]

There is a bit of jaggedness at the seam of the left and right-hand sides. Hopefully, the errors will average out. We could have put a seam at the interface with more elaborate model construction. Now, we can estimate the fluxes using the following:

```
gradT[x_, y_, z_] = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][sol][x, y, z], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][sol][x, y, z], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][sol][x, y, z]};
f = NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[(gradT @@@ center3[[#]]), bn3[[#]]] . 
    area3[[#]] &;
f[posXids]
f[negXids]
f[posXids~Join~negXids]
(* -0.952311 *)
(* -2.96147 *)
(* -3.91378 *)
```

These results agree with the OP integral formulation quite well and are significantly faster.

## Comparison to another code

When possible, it is always good to compare the *Mathematica* FEM results with another FEM code. In this case, I will show that the Mathematica results compare favorably with the FEM code COMSOL. First, I will create a [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) for comparison purposes.

```
surf = {{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 
     1.001^2}, {"XStackedPlanes", {7.5}}, {"YStackedPlanes", {0}}, \
{"ZStackedPlanes", {-0.8}}, {"BackPlanes"}};
SliceContourPlot3D[sol[x, y, z], surf, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
 Contours -> 11, PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", PlotRange -> {-0.001, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica slice contour plot]

Here is the comparable COMSOL plot:

[image: COMSOL plot]

As you can see, the visualizations compare favorably.

We also can see that the integrations of gradT on the left and right hemispherical cap surfaces also agreed to within about 2%

| Application | Left | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Mathematica* | -2.96147 | -0.95414 |
| COMSOL | -3.0255 | -0.952755 |
| %Diff | 2.16226 | 0.0465888 |

## Update in response to a comment about low Péclet numbers

The Péclet number is defined by:

$$Pe=\frac{Advective\ Transport\ Rate}{Diffusive\ Transport\ Rate}$$

So, as the Péclet number goes down the Advective component becomes less significant indicating that a "wind tunnel" is perhaps not the best model to study this problem. Although you may want to consider modifying the geometry, you can substantially mitigate the effects of low Péclet numbers by changing the default wall conditions to `DirichletCondition`'s. Here is a logarithmic sweep from Pe numbers from 0.01 to 100 (note that this process is slow):

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[T[x, y, z], x] == 
     1/P Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {DirichletCondition[
      T[x, y, z] == 1., ElementMarker == 3], 
     DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 0., 
      Or @@ (ElementMarker == # & /@ {4, 6, 7})]}}, 
   T, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, {P}];
surf = {{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 
     1.001^2}, {"XStackedPlanes", {7.5}}, {"YStackedPlanes", {0}}, \
{"ZStackedPlanes", {-0.8}}, {"BackPlanes"}};
frames = SliceContourPlot3D[pfun[#][x, y, z], 
     surf, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, Contours -> 11, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
     ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", PlotRange -> {-0.001, 1}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> N@#] & /@ (10^# & /@ 
     Subdivide[-2, 2, 20]);
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Parametric sweep of Péclet numbers]

Comment: Is it possible that we can solve coupeld pde  (e.g. FSI) using Mathametica Solver?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Of course, the subject of FSI is very broad and generally quite difficult. If you can assume that the deformations are so small that they do not affect the fluid flow (e.g., thermal stress due to transient transfer from a fluid), then you could do a "FSI" problem following this [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/ThermalLoad.html). Significant deformation would require the ability for Mathematica to solve the mesh deformation equations on the fluid side, which I have yet to see an example. Consider making a feature request.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Actually, I am looking for an example for Staggered Scheme for NDsolve coupled fields. or in other words, how to set the staggered solver in mathematica.

Comment: @Tim Laska, this is more than I expected!! I am more than grateful. To justify my silence: I am studying your code and I will surely ask you some questions soon (if I can bother you again).

Comment: @umby Thank you very much!  I will see what I can do.

Comment: @Tim Laska, I have to confess I did not really catch the core of your solution, and this is my fault alone. For example, I do not understand why your solution does not work for small value of Pe (Pe is the Peclet number, so a small Pe means a slow flow along X); the calculated temperature field is quite unrealistic in this case. But it seems to me that your code contains only a splitting of the domain and a mesh refinement function. Or probably this arises from the asymmetric nature of the domain with the upstream section much shorter than the downstream region?

Comment: @umby See update.

Comment: @Tim Laska, your code can be applied to different geometries, as an ellipsoid with two axes of length 1 and a third axis of length `p`? In this case the geometry description would be:
`p=2;`
`Pe=15;`
`tip=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0,0,0},{1,1,p}],MaxCellMeasure->.00125,Axes->True,AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"}];`
`refCuboid=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{-1.5,0,-p-0.5},{3.5,1.5,0}],MaxCellMeasure->.01,Axes->True,AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"}];`
Your section "Summing up the discretized data", seems suitable for any geometry, or does it need an adjustment?

Comment: @umby You will need to make a couple of changes `tip=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, p}], MaxCellMeasure -> .005, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]; domCuboid=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ Cuboid[{-2.5, 0, -3.8}, {7.5, 4, 0}], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}];` and it will work.  You need to coarsen the mesh on the tip otherwise gradT throws some errors presumably due to mesh quality.  The second change is to make the ceilings of the domCuboid and refCuboid align.

Comment: However, this line `posXids = Position[center3, _?(#[[1]] >= 0 &), 1] // Flatten` gives an error message: `Part::partd: Part specification List[[1]] is longer than depth of object`. Can you please help me on this point?

Comment: @umby It gives a warning that you can ignore. I have updated the post with an expression that avoids the warning.

Comment: @Tim Laska, it works fine now, many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple of different ideas for generating the meshes. This works in 12.3

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Pe = 15;
p = 2/10;
reg = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-2.5, 0, -3.8}, {7.5, 4, -0.8}], 
   Ball[]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 3.5];
```

The key here is the `AccuracyGoal`. In version 12.3 the 3D default boundary mesh generator is OpenCascade. OpenCascade will not refine flat boundaries if the accuracy goal is increased.

```
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Visualize the boundary mesh and it's boundary markers:

```
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
Show[
 bmesh["Edgeframe"],
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
      colors)]]
 , Epilog -> Inset[LineLegend[colors, groups], Scaled[{0.85, 0.6}]]
 ]
```

[image]

The solution can then be found with

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[T[x, y, z], x] == 
     1/Pe Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {DirichletCondition[
      T[x, y, z] == 1., ElementMarker == 7], 
     DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 0., ElementMarker == 1]}}, 
   T, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
```

Another idea is to split the cap. This can be done with the OpenCascadeLink. The idea is to create a left and right part of the geometry, take the faces and merge them back together.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
rleft = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{-2.5, 0, -3.8}, {0, 4, -0.8}], 
   Ball[]];
rright = RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -3.8}, {7.5, 4, -0.8}], 
   Ball[]];
left = OpenCascadeShape[rleft];
right = OpenCascadeShape[rright];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[
  Flatten[{OpenCascadeShapeFaces[left], 
    OpenCascadeShapeFaces[right]}]]

OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Note, that we have a split along the x=0 plane. Next, we generate a boundary mesh

```
(bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape, 
    "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {(*"LinearDeflection"->0.00025*)
        "AngularDeflection" -> 0.025
      }])["Wireframe"]
```

You can tell OpenCascade to either use a linear deflection or an angular deflection (See documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html#295318819))

Inspect the boundary mesh and it's markers

```
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
Show[
 bmesh["Edgeframe"],
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
      colors)]]
 , Epilog -> Inset[LineLegend[colors, groups], Scaled[{0.85, 0.6}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Inspect the detail of the cap:

```
bmesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 7 || ElementMarker == 9, 
  "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]]
```

[image]

Generate the mesh:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Solve the PDE

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[T[x, y, z], x] == 
     1/Pe Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {DirichletCondition[
      T[x, y, z] == 1., ElementMarker == 7 || ElementMarker == 9], 
     DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 0., ElementMarker == 1]}}, 
   T, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
z1 = -0.8;
DensityPlot[sol[x, y, z1], {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
DensityPlot[sol[x, 0, z], {x, -4, 4}, {z, -0.8, -2}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

```
FEMNBoundaryIntegrate[
 Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] . {x, y, z}, {x, y, z}, mesh, 
 ElementMarker == 7]

-2.98032


FEMNBoundaryIntegrate[
 Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] . {x, y, z}, {x, y, z}, mesh, 
 ElementMarker == 9]

-0.946663
```

You can still use a `MeshRefinementFunction` to refine the mesh away from the cap.

As a side note, check out these new (12.3) OpenCascade tutorials: [Book Shelf Bracket](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/BookShelfBracket.html) and [Helical Bevel Gear](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/HelicalBevelGear.html)

Comment: Is `FEMNBoundaryIntegrate` a new addition?  I like it.  Also, is it still true that `MeshRefinementFunction` will only operate on the volume elements leaving a big jump in element size from the volume to the surface?  I was trying to avoid that.  I initially tried a combination of OpenCascade and `FEMAddOns` to union the bmesh's, but it failed.  That is why I fell back to the ` BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`.

Comment: @TimLaska, `FEMNBoundaryIntegrate` and `FEMNIntegrate` are not new, they are the back bone of `NIntegrate` for the cases when the method goes to FEM. I never really documented them because NIntegrate did a good job. However, they have one 'feature' that makes them valuable and that is the 4rth argument. Where you can specify a predicate. In principal one can have this predicate in the first argument like `FEMNBoundaryIntegrate[If[pred, 1,0]*val,{x,y,..}, bmesh]` but in some cases this gives the wrong result. So please be careful with that, probably better to use the 4 arg version.

Comment: @TimLaska, concerning `MeshRefinementFunction`: this is a WL interface to a C language interface both Triangle and TetGen provide and both tools do not preform a mesh refinement on the boundary. So in theory what would need to happen is that the `MeshRefinementFunction` would need to be passed to the boundary mesh generator refine the boundary and then during the mesh generation that same function would then refine the full mesh. I'll think a bit about that, but please do not hold your breath for that - I am so consumed with structural mechancis right now that I can not foresee when I'll be

Comment: @TimLaska able to look into something like this.

Comment: @TimLaska, slightly tangential, I'd like to point you to another update, that I think, you might find useful: You can now use `NeumannValue` in `NIntegrate`. For example, if you want to compute the heat loss through a radiation boundary you can directly use the `NeumannValue` that specifies the radiation condition, like shown [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/JouleHeating.html#1008590087). Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive reply! Structural mechanics is a deep but important area. As you know by many of my answers, I like to strive that good meshing is a key factor in obtaining good solutions. I try to mimic some of the functionality that I find in my proprietary meshers, but I fear some of my extensive workarounds could turn some users off. As models get more complex, I think the ability to specify a boundary integration by element marker is quite a nice feature. Good work!

Comment: @TimLaska, I hope that before to long the anisotropic mesh generation you provided here will make it into the kernel, that should reduce the amount of programing needed to generate those kind of meshes; meshing is probably an area that one can always find new things to improve.... One other feature I'd really like to have is being able to specify 2D geometries in OpenCascade and then project them into 3D, for extrusion, lofting, etc.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you, @user21!

Comment: @umby anything specifically, you find interesting?

Comment: OpenCascadeLink and OpenCascade works really well (the online documentation is absolutely complete), they are not available in 12.0, I think.

Comment: @umby, you can find the sources for the  [OpenCascadeLink paclet](https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink). Contributions are very welcome ;-) I am glad you find it useful.